# Writes value in the same line

Tags: go, go-templates

I’ve the following code which works to generate the names
One after another:

```
{{- range .File.apps}}

{{ .Name}}

{{- end}}
```

**This prints**

```
app1

app2

app3
```

The problem is that I need to get it In the **same line** and not one after other

```
app1 app2 app3
```

When I try like following it remove the firsts entry and put only the last value. i.e. i'll get only `app3`

```
{{- range .File.apps}} {{ .Name}} {{- end}}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please include a self-contained piece of code that reproduces your problem. What you posted should not output what you are describing.

Comment: @TimCooper - what do you mean by  "not output what you are describing" ? can you please elaborate ?

Comment: There is no reason why changing your template loop to be on a single line would cause items to be omitted. Something else is obviously going wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-` character prevents new lines so adding a `-` before the closing `}}` should do the trick.

https://play.golang.org/p/a-P-yPJtm9W

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"
import "text/template"

const temp = `
{{- range .Apps -}}
{{- .Name -}}
{{- end -}}
`

type file struct {
    Apps []app
}

type app struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    data := file{
        Apps: []app{
            app{"foo"}, 
            app{"bar"},
        },
    }
    t := template.Must(template.New("foo").Parse(temp))

    err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
}
```